# IF command not processing parameters properly in my batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create a batch that works in cooperation with ImageMagick to convert SVGs to PNG. I'm also trying to get it to do different operations depending on the parameters passed to it.

```
svg2png -all
```

The above command should tell it to convert every SVG in the folder.

```
svg2png examplename.svg
```

This command should tell it to only convert a single SVG.

My problem is that I can't get it to acknowledge that -all isn't a filename, but rather a parameter, so it instead checks for a file named -all, which of course doesn't exist.

Can anyone help? The following is my code:

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="" goto noparameters
if "%1"==-all goto convertall
if exist "%1" (
 goto convertsingle
) else (
 goto badfilename
)
goto noparameters

:convertall
echo.
for %%a in ("*.svg") do (
 echo Now converting %%a.
 magick convert -size 512x512 %%a %%a.png
)
goto endbatch

:convertsingle
echo.
echo Now converting %1.
magick convert -size 512x512 %1 %1.png
goto endbatch

:noparameters
echo.
echo No parameters specified.
goto endbatch

:badfilename
echo.
echo SVG2PNG could not find the specified file.
goto endbatch

:endbatch
```

Comment: If you have quotes on one side of your IF comparison, you need them on the other side.

Comment: @Squashman Thank you! Can't believe it was that simple. Please post that in an answer so I can check it as the solution. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quotes are part of the comparison.  If you have them on one side of the comparison they must be on the other side for them to be equal.

```
 if "%1"=="-all" goto convertall
```